# VB script ADODB.Stream creating infinite while loop

Tags: vbscript

I have vbs file. It will fetch the records from sql server 2000 Database.
using do while loop,
then It extract the data column from record set 
Using the steam object, create the file & write the content of the zip file
But i am getting infinite loop.

Please find the DB records for sample

File_id      File_Name    File_content(blob datatype)

23127376     File_1      afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127377     File_2      afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127378     File_3      afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127379     File_4      afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127380     File_5      afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127381     File_6      afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127382     File_7      afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127383     File_8      afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127384     File_9      afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127385     File_10     afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127386     File_11     afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127387     File_12     afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127388     File_13     afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127389     File_14     afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127390     File_15     afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

23127391     File_16     afdfasdf253asdf6asdf52asd45fasf

Please view the code below

```
DO
     Set lobjStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     lobjStream.Mode = 3 ' adModeReadWrite   3       Read/write.
     lobjStream.Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary      1       Binary data
     lobjStream.Open
     SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K = ObjRS("SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K")
     logMessage = "[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: " & SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K
     logFilte.WriteLine (logMessage)
     lobjStream.Write ObjRS("DFMB02_FILE_BLOB_I").Value 
     lobjStream.SaveToFile ZipPath & ObjRS("DFMB02_FILE_N").Value, 2    
     ZipFile = ZipPath & ObjRS("DFMB02_FILE_N").Value       
     ZIPFldPath = Left(ObjRS("DFMB02_FILE_N").Value, Len(ObjRS("DFMB02_FILE_N").Value) - 4)

     ObjRS.movenext
     set lobjStream =  Nothing
Loop While ObjRS.EOF = False
```

After sometime, i will get infinite loop. Please find the log for this code.

```
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127376
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127377
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127378
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127379 
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127380
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127381
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127382
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127383
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127384
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127385
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127385
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127385
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127385
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127385
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127385
[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: 23127385
```

Could you please assist on this issue

Answer (score 1):

You should properly handle checking the EOF in your Do statement rather than the While statement. and you can break the loop by checking the last saved value.

```
Dim lastsaved : lastsaved = ""
Do While Not ObjRS.EOF

    Set lobjStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    lobjStream.Mode = 3 ' adModeReadWrite   3       Read/write.
    lobjStream.Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary      1       Binary data
    lobjStream.Open
    Dim check : check = ObjRS("SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K")
    If lastsaved = check Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        lastsaved = check
        SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K = check
    End If
    logMessage = "[Record] File ID (SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K) :: " & SDFMB02_FILE_ID_K
    logFilte.WriteLine (logMessage)
    lobjStream.Write ObjRS("DFMB02_FILE_BLOB_I").Value 
    lobjStream.SaveToFile ZipPath & ObjRS("DFMB02_FILE_N").Value, 2    
    ZipFile = ZipPath & ObjRS("DFMB02_FILE_N").Value       
    ZIPFldPath = Left(ObjRS("DFMB02_FILE_N").Value, Len(ObjRS("DFMB02_FILE_N").Value) - 4)

    ObjRS.movenext
    Set lobjStream =  Nothing
Loop
```

Comment: +1.  I usually check `BOF` as well.  So something like `Do While Not ObjRS.BOF And Not ObjRS.EOF`  It might be superfluous, but I don't recall what the .BOF and .EOF property values are when the recordset returns zero rows.

Comment: Hi Rich 1)This loop works fine for 10000 records but the hanging problem comes when there are more than 80000 records. 2) Prime facie the do-while loop of yours and mine are logically correct. Could you please elaborate what is the difference between yours and mine do-while  loop?

Comment: Sure no problem. My loop checks its last value and looks for changes. If no changes are present it exits the do loop